# Within Java Library, lotus.domino.Session class method createDateTime() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

A Java file in the Domino Designer Java library folder (not a Java Agent in the Agents folder) when called from XPage SSJS will throw a NullPointerException for standard methods like `createDateTime()`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.base64.Base64;
import lotus.domino.*;

public class Tools extends AgentBase  {

  ...

  public void getSession( ) throws IOException {

    Session s   = getSession();
    DateTime dt = s.createDateTime("Today");    // NullPointerException
    String n    = s.getEffectiveUserName();     // NullPointerException

    ...

  }

}
```

If the Java code is saved as a Java Agent, then there is no exception thrown.

Is there another way to set a NotesDateTime field with 'Now" in Java without having to use the session.createDateTime() method?

Is the AgentBase extended or is there another extension to use when using a Java library (not an agent)?

What other ways are there to create a lotus.domino.Session that might help?

**UPDATE:**  In **plugin.xml**, I added **com.ibm.xsp.extlib** as a **Dependency**, and the Java class compiled error-free.

**XPages Properties**, Page Generation Xpage Library **com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library** is checked.

From server console, **tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib** returns:

```
> tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
osgi> "Framework is launched."
id  State       Bundle
114 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl1_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=117
115 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl2_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=117
116 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl3_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=117
117 STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Fragments=116, 115, 114
118 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl1_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=121
119 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl2_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=121
120 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl3_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=121
121 STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Fragments=119, 118, 120
122 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl1_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=125
123 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl2_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=125
124 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl3_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=125
125 STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Fragments=123, 124, 122
126 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl1_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=129
127 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl2_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=129
128 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl3_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=129
129 STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Fragments=127, 128, 126
130 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl1_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=133
131 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl2_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=133
132 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl3_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=133
133 STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Fragments=132, 130, 131
134 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.nl1_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=137
135 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.nl2_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=137
136 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.nl3_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Master=137
137 STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
                Fragments=135, 136, 134
138 STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058
```

Note that the log says **STARTING com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v10_00_20180115-1058**

What does that mean?  I've also add an updatesite.nsf file to the server and updated the Notes.ini with **OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=install\update-site.nsf**.

When starting HTTP, there is no message that the OSGI is being loaded into the run time.

The error I get when trying to set the Session:

**NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/xsp/extlib/util/ExtLibUtil**

Isn't this class already included with Domino 9.0.1FP10 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the session with

```
Session s = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
```

Your subsequent code lines will work then.

```
public class Tools  {
  ...
  public void yourMethod() {
    Session s   = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
    DateTime dt = s.createDateTime("Today");
    String n    = s.getEffectiveUserName();
    ...
  }
}
```

The function `getSession()` you used works for Java agents only.

Don't forget to include the extension library into your project:

[image]

Comment: How do I import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil?  Says name cannot be resolved...

Comment: I cannot find the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util library.  Where is it?  I've got com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core, com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino, com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile and others, but not com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.

Comment: I found it -- from Package Explorer, plugin.xml Dependencies tab.

Comment: Still getting error when trying to set the Session: 
NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/xsp/extlib/util/ExtLibUtil
Isn't this class already included with Domino 9 server?  Running FP10;

Comment: For some reason it took a very long time for the above libraries to change from STARTING to RESOLVED.  It's working now.